# Is the water damage or just age?

Tags: windows

Giant entry way decorative glass window above front door.  About 20 years old.

[image: Cornor of window]

[image]

I don't see or feel moisture, per se.

Is this water damage (*hence replacement time*) or just in need of fresh paint?

Comment: What probably happened was not leakage but condensation.

Answer (score 1):

You have had some moisture problems there, either now or in the past. The mildew and cracked joints are telltale signs. Before you just replace the whole thing, remove some of the lower trim and investigate further to see if there is damage underneath. Also check the outside caulking and trim for signs of damage. You might find that previous problems were fixed but the cosmetics were never completed.

Comment: Similar idea so not adding a new answer but the past moisture may be condensation, that may recur in future EG it may be seasonal.  If so you'll need to figure out what's causing it, and if you can't correct it use really good paint and caulking on the window frame or replace it with a PVC or aluminum one.

Comment: I agree my mom has a very large picture window in her front room prior to me adding bathroom vents the window would sweat all the time and keeping that inside cil painted and clean was a chore , after adding bathroom vents the amount of moisture from the normal condensation was greatly reduced.